# Deleting a file with question marks in the name (another encoding) in Debian

Tags: debian, rm

I have a file with the name like `?????????????????????? ???????????????????????? ??????????.png` in my directory. It seems to me that file was created under windows with russian name. I pulled it with git and now  I am unable to compile my program. And I am unable to delete it in debian.

```
rm: cannot remove `??????????????????????': No such file or directory

rm: cannot remove `????????????????????????': No such file or directory

rm: cannot remove `??????????.png': No such file or directory
```

I tried to use quotes around file name, but it doesn't work.

How should delete files with names like this?

Comment: The question marks probably stand for unrecognized unicode characters--I would try switching to a terminal font with unicode support for Russian characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `rm -i <wildcard>`...

```
(py26_dfl)[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$ rm -i *ng
rm: remove regular file `IMAG0004-1.png'? n
rm: remove regular file `??????????.png'? y
(py26_dfl)[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$
```

Answer (score 3):

The use of wildcards, as suggested in [another answer](https://superuser.com/a/510053/257269), is often the faster way to select a subset of files from your directory, but not always it is possible to use it (e.g. in the previous case at least you have the extension suffix in *understandable characters*).

```
rm -i *ng   # means remove all files that finish for ng
```

**Another way can be to use the [inode](http://www.linfo.org/inode.html) number of the file.**
With an `ls -i` you will have the list of the files in the current directory with the *inode number* followed from the file name. It follows an example, obtained with `ls -i1` just to have the output with a file for each line:

```
14549004 Various_Command_.sh
14549512 Convert_Scan_Png_To_Jpg.sh
14579439 FILE_TO_DELETE
```

After you can delete or move or execute any command you want, selecting the file by its *inode number*. E.g: to `remove` the file `FILE_TO_DELETE` with the *inode number* 14579439 it's possible to write:

```
find . -inum 14579439 -exec rm -i {} \;
```

Note: the option `-i` after the remove command exists to force the system to prompt before every removal.
For the use of find you can read the [man page](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/find1.html) or search on web some [tutorial](https://www.google.com/#q=find+linux+tutorial).

Comment: If confirmation is not required, an alternative is to do e.g. `find . -inum 36384549` to view the files. Then just `find . -inum 36384549 | xargs rm` to remove them all. I find that syntax more intuitive and easier to remember.